# Invalid Model State with Nested Class

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following POST method:

```
public class ModelOuter
{
    public int P1 { get; set; }

    public int P2 { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Test(int i, ModelOuter m)
{
    var result = String.Empty;
    var json = new JsonResult();

    if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
        result = $"good {m.P1} {m.P2}";
    else
        result = "bad";

    json.Data = new { result };

    return json;
}
```

I would like to pass the data for `ModelOuter` in the POST data, but I get an invalid model state.

Here is the successful POST request:

```
params = {
    i: 0,
};

$.ajax({
    url: "@this.Url.Content("~/Event/test")",
    cache: false,
    data: params,
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    traditional: true,
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { }
});
```

It comes back with this result:

```
{"result":"good 0 0"}
```

Here is the unsuccessful request:

```
params = {
    i: 0,
    m: {
        p1: 1,
        p2: 2,
    }
};

$.ajax({
    url: "@this.Url.Content("~/Event/test")",
    cache: false,
    data: params,
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    traditional: true,
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { }
});
```

It comes back with this result:

```
{"result":"bad"}
```

The header information (according to Chrome) is as follows:

```
i: 0
m: [object Object]

i=0&m=%5Bobject+Object%5D
```

So I'm guessing the issue is somehow related to how the nested JSON object is being serialised?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class M
{
    public int p1 { get; set; }
    public int p2 { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int i { get; set; }
    public M m { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
public JsonResult Test(RootObject data) { … }
```

Not sure but I think it's being messed up trying to break your parameter into two parameters